# how to call a function onclick (reference error)

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, onclick, jquery-tabs

I'm working with Twitter Bootstrap, I have a link which when clicked I want to open one of the accordian tabs (and scroll nice and smooth)

It works first time, if  i open other tabs then try the link again i get a reference error saying 'openTab' is not defined.

Here's what I have so far:

HTML:

```
<a href='#reviews' class="star-ratingT" onclick="openTab()">Write a review</a>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function(openTab) {
$(".review-tab").trigger("click");
});
```

Comment: Is that random ` in your code or just bad markup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".stat-ratingT").click(function () { 
        $(".review-tab").trigger("click");
    });
});
```

Comment: 1) posted after my suggestion 2) does not cancel the click

Comment: do i need to cancel the click?

Comment: Yes. And it is nice to accept the [first posted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21550207/295783)

Comment: 1) Didn't notice. sorry. 2) Didn't notice he ask for it. Anyway @user1199795, I usually prefer <span> tag with style=cursor:pointer;. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

change

```
$(function(openTab) {
```

with

```
function openTab() {
```

Comment: still getting ReferenceError: openTab is not defined

Comment: is it because the jquery library is loaded after the <a> tag?

Comment: keep this function out of `jquery` dom ready functions. add it in script tags

Comment: Not enough. It is not the only problem

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script
$(function() {
  $(".star-ratingT").on("click",function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // cancel the actual link
    $(".review-tab").trigger("click");
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

change this one:

```
$(function(openTab) {
    $(".review-tab").trigger("click");
});
```

to this:

```
function openTab() {
    $(".review-tab").trigger("click");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about removing it from the A tag and just putting it in the jQuery as well?

```
$(".star-ratingT").click(function(){
    openTab();
});
```